# NSDocumentDirectory changes after each install

Tags: ios, macos, cocoa, provisioning

I install my application using an ad-hoc provisioning.
Each time i install the application, the NSDocumentDirectory is different. The GUID at the end of the path changes.

Why?

Answer (score 1):

Every ios app is a sandbox. That means that whenever the app is installed, it gets a unique guid to operate within that "space" and only that space. This goes for all phones, for example your phone has guid a' the other user's phone will have a guid b'.

Similarly, each app creates its own filesystem directories (/documents, /library, etc) to operate within.

If you want to access asset files, do them through NSFileManager functions (combined with NSDocumentDirectory) or have a shared itunes folder for documents.

Comment: But it is the same application that i install twice. Why the id changes?

Comment: It goes for every application. If you delete the app from your testing device it generates a new guid.

Comment: I did not delete the app. I installed it again as an "update" (new bundle version).

Comment: Hmm strange. Did you change anything other than the version tag in info.plist?

Comment: No, did not change anything else

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand the problem, is the content of your document directory modified? or your problem is that you try to store in your app the guid?